# Addressing "chattiness" in a REST API

Tags: api, rest

REST API's seem to be inherently "chatty", since you provide links to sub-resources in the response instead of embedding them directly. For example, let's say you had a product and reviews, when you perform a `GET` on `/api/products/123`, you might get something like this:

```
{
   "name": "A monkey"
   "cost", "$5000.00",
   "reviews": [
        "/api/reviews/1",
        "/api/reviews/2",
        "/api/reviews/3"
        ...
        "/api/reviews/2071",
    ]
}
```

To display all the reviews, you would need to perform 2071 `GET` requests. Perhaps some of this can be mitigated by paging (perhaps showing only 10 reviews at a time). Are there other ways alleviate this? Is there an acceptable "aggregate representation" that can be used to minimized chattiness?

Comment: How is this question too broad? I'm asking for a solution regarding a specific attribute of REST API's (i.e., chattiness). I even narrowed it down further by asking if there was an acceptable "aggregate representation" that one can use.

Comment: Take a look at http://jsonapi.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN this particular case, yes, however, if it's well defined and uses caching per the original specification, any subsequent requests should hit cache, not the full API.

> Cacheable
>       As on the World Wide Web, clients can cache responses. Responses must therefore, implicitly or explicitly, define themselves as cacheable, or not, to prevent clients reusing stale or inappropriate data in response to further requests. Well-managed caching partially or completely eliminates some client–server interactions, further improving scalability and performance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: and normally there is a collection based api, not a single document/page based api, you should be able to aggregate results and page through using a page size parameter

Answer (score 4):

Possibly it depends on how you look at it. Since reviews are always bound to some product, you could consider `/api/products/123/reviews` as the resource containing all reviews for the monkey. Then doing `GET` there can return something like

```
[{ "id": "1", "reviewer": "vivin", ... }, ... ]
```

(possibly with some paging on that list). In this way `GET` on `/api/products/123/reviews/2071` only returns the the specific review

```
{ "id": "2071, "reviewer": "subsub", "The monkey stinks." }
```